How do I apply a lemma to both sides of an equality hypothesis?
I have the following Coq code:
Require Import Arith Lia.

Lemma mul2eq : forall a b : nat, 2 * a = 2 * b -> a = b.
Proof.
  lia.
Qed.

Lemma add_twice_is_mul2 : forall n : nat, n + n = 2 * n.
Proof.
  lia.
Qed.

Theorem invert : forall a b : nat, a + a = b + b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros.
  ???
Qed.

I'm trying to prove invert. I have a hypothesis in invert: H: a + a = b + b. I can see the path that I need to take to prove invert. I need to somehow apply add_twice_is_mul2 to both sides of H, which will give me 2 * a = 2 * b. Then I'll apply mul2eq to that, giving me a = b, which will solve the proof.
However, I don't know how to apply add_twice_is_mul2 to both  sides of H, or if it's even possible. Can anyone give me some advice? I've heard some hype about f_equal but I can't seem to get it to work in my case.

Use transitivity and symmetry of equality: $2 * a = a + a = b + b = 2 * b$.

@NaïmFavier What do you mean by "use"? How would I apply this in code?

Theorem invert : forall a b : nat, a + a = b + b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply mul2eq.
  rewrite <- ? add_twice_is_mul2.
  exact H.
Qed.

or
Theorem invert : forall a b : nat, a + a = b + b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply mul2eq.
  transitivity (a + a).
  symmetry. apply add_twice_is_mul2.
  transitivity (b + b).
  assumption.
  apply add_twice_is_mul2.
Qed.


I assume that you want to do forward reasoning, i.e. apply the lemma mul2eq last. For this, one typically uses the in modifier, like so:
Theorem invert : forall a b : nat, a + a = b + b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros a b H.
  rewrite (add_twice_is_mul2 a) in H.
  rewrite (add_twice_is_mul2 b) in H.
  eapply mul2eq in H.
  assumption.
Qed.

The in modifier applies to quite a few tactics. In more complicated cases, one can use assert, or pose proof.
